# yii2 renaming migration file to reorder the migration error

Tags: php, yii, migration, yii2

I'm trying to rename migration files to reorder the migration, but I found an error.

I know the name of migration file is generate based on timestamp, example:

```
m150311_012031_create_place_table.php
m150311_020901_create_meeting_table.php
```

I forgot I should create `meeting` table first before I create `place` table, so what I do I run `yii migrate/down all` to rollback the migration first, I rename the file to reorder it like so:

```
m150311_012030_create_meeting_table.php
m150311_012031_create_place_table.php
```

and run `yii migrate up/all` but I got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'm150311_012030_create_meeting_table' not found in C:\wamp\www\yii2advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\MigrateController.php on line 113
```

I think `composer dumpautoload` will fix this, but nothing happens. I know I can just delete and create all the migration from start again, but what if I already created 10 migration files, and I forgot I should have create migration on 2nd order.

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not recommended to do this except you did not push your commits to working repository yet.

The problem is that besides changing file names you also need to change class names, because of the way migrations are organized.

Migration class names are exactly the same as file names without `.php` extension.

**1)** `m150311_012031_create_place_table.php`

Change file name to `m150311_020901_create_meeting_table.php` and class name to `class m150311_020901_create_meeting_table`.

**2)** `m150311_020901_create_meeting_table.php`

Change file name to `m150311_012031_create_place_table.php` and class name to `class m150311_012031_create_place_table`.

Comment: so there is no solution for this?

Comment: Why not? I mentioned that you also need to change class names according to file names.

Comment: Ah I see, I forgot to change the class name, thank you for point that out sir, you save my day :)

Comment: Is there a way to set an order to run migrations? This is a work-around, I don't want to do it, because I have modules, whose migrations I cannot rename on every project